# JavaScript Insert delimiter and join content of array as one string

Tags: javascript

Write a function that accepts three arguments (an array, delimiter, and a number). The function would join
content of the array to form a string, inserting the delimiter after every nth element of the array and displays
resulting string in console:

```
functionName([0, 2, “Hello”, 7, “TO”, “---“], “+”, 3);
```

// would produce following message in console:

```
output => 02Hello+7TO---+
```

Comment: nice HW question, what did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let res = '';
function joinLst(lst, deli, num) {
  for (let i = 0; i < lst.length; i++) {
      res += lst[i]
  if((i + 1) % num == 0) {
    res += deli
  }
  }
  return res

}

console.log(joinLst([0, 2, 'Hello', 7, 'TO', '---'], '+', 3))
```

Nothing special just basic for loop and i statement.

I just kept on adding elements from the list to the `res` and also checked if the position in now equal to the number provided to the function, then add the `deli` at that point.

Comment: Also note that % function returns the remainder if a number is dived by another. So here as the index is 1 less than its position (like first position has index zero) that is why, i added 1 to i and then checked the remainder

Answer (score 0):

it is a quite simple function.
I haven't added comments so you can read the code and try to understand how it works and why.

```js
'use strict';

const myList = [0, 2, 'Hello', 7, 'TO', '---'];

const myDelimiter = "+";

const myNth = 3;

console.log(nameIt(myList, myDelimiter, myNth));

function nameIt(list, delimiter, nth) {
    let delimiterCounter = 1;
    let finalString = "";

    for (let element of list) {
        finalString += element.toString();

        if (nth === delimiterCounter) {
            delimiterCounter = 1;

            finalString += delimiter;
        } else {
            delimiterCounter++;
        }
    }

    return finalString;
}
```